# ROS windows crash while getting NodeHandler

Tags: ros, windows, node, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've got a trouble using ROS in Windows :(. I'm with the publisher and subscriber tutorial in windows. I compiled it fine but while executing it, it crash due to an access violation...

If I execute it with out executing in a console "roscore" it says that cant connect to master

[ERROR] [139405801.88193503]: [RegisterPublisher] Failed to contact master at [JANE-vaio:11311]. Retryin...

So then I tried with roscore (As I read, it's always necessary). But then I get the access violation inside the line:
"ros::NodeHandle n;"

If I debugged inside i got that crash in the line "initRemappings(remappings);"

Can anyone helps me?

Thanks in advance!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135986/ros-windows-crash-while-getting-nodehandler/) by [Bardo91](https://answers.ros.org/users/12326/bardo91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2014-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I had same issue with ROS Hydro and Visual studio 2013 express. Don't know what the actual problem was but changing Platform Toolset setting from visual studio 2013 to visual studio 2010 or Windows7.1SDK and building again solved it for me.

---

Originally posted by [Raitalaama](https://answers.ros.org/users/18760/raitalaama/) with karma: 56 on 2014-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1